# Vue Drawer keep showing up on resize and I need to keep it closed

Tags: vue.js

I have a multi page application and on my toolbar.vue page I have

```
 <v-navigation-drawer v-model="drawer" 
    left fixed app dark disable-route-watcher>
```

and at the

```
 created: function() {  
    if (this.$router.currentRoute.name === "pubs") {
      this.drawer = false;
      this.ToolbarTitle = "Publications Worksheet";
      this.isDisabled = true;
    }
```

This works great when the page is first opened but if the browser is resize the Drawer show up.  If I refresh the page with the current size it goes away.  Is there a way to keep in closed?

Comment: from the vuetify *[documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/navigation-drawers)* ... `disable-resize-watcher` - Will automatically open/close drawer when resized depending if mobile or desktop ... so just add `disable-resize-watcher` to disable this functionality

Comment: Thanks-- I had added disable-route-watcher - I think I added the wrong item  Thanks